# ORA-12154 : TNS: connection identifier specified could not be resolved

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames

I'm performing an OracleConnection to contact a distant DataBase, like this:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION(ADDRESS_LIST=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXXX));User Id=XX_XXX_XXX; Password=XXXXXXXXXXX");
```

Every informations hidden are correct and correspond to the Oracle Database.

When I do `conn.Open();` I have the error: ORA-12514: TNS: connection identifier specified could not be resolved

I've heard it's probably because of the tnsnames.ORA I have copied/past the tnsnames.ORA of a colleague to mine and nothing changed.

I have searched on many forums and websites, noone seems to get my answer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greetings,

Flo.

EDIT1:

After having tried a SQLplus connection on command-line, it worked. Visual studio seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is the listener started? Run `lsnrctl status`, show the output, please.

Comment: I suppose you mean the listener of the Oracle Database? I can't access it, but I can phone'em to ask'em. I come back with the information soon. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add this connection string in your TNSnames.ora file on your machine.

Comment: `new OracleCollection` are you sure. is not `new OracleConnection`?

Comment: Yes, miss copy it's new OracleConnection. I have added the connection string in my TNSnames.ora file @Rex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection string. It seems like you  are missing a pair of parentheses:

`OracleConnection conn = new OracleCollection("Data Source=((DESCRIPTION(ADDRESS_LIST=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXXX)));User Id=XX_XXX_XXX; Password=XXXXXXXXXXX");`

Comment: I think it's a fail rewrite, I haven't copy pasted. I check this.

Comment: It wasn't a fail, I trully forgot a pair of parentheses. But It doesn't change nothing. I still have the error.

Comment: On a second glance: You are also missing a en equal sign after the description keyword: `DESCRIPTION=(...`

Comment: I try with the sign "=" and I have a different error now: `ORA-12533 TNS illegal ADDRESS parameter`

Comment: I have now a different error. I accept your answer and create a new topic with the new error, the changes I've done, etc.